# SFML returning Vertex array

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to draw a straight line in my window using SFML. When I write my code in `main()` function, it works. But when I try to implement same code to a function and call it `while(window.isOpen())` loop it doesn't work. There is probably something that I'm missing creating the function or returning the Vertex array.

Function:

```
sf::Vertex *drawLine(int posX1, int posY1, int posX2, int posY2) {
    sf::Vertex line[] = {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(posX1, posY1), sf::Color::Red),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(posX2, posY2), sf::Color::Red)
    };
    return line;
}
```

How I call this: (in while loop)

```
window.draw(drawLine(0,0,100,100), 2, sf::Lines);
```

Comment: you're returning an address to a local variable

Comment: @TrebledJ Yes that's where I was wrong. Thank you!